# Directly calling `clojure.lang.Compiler.compile` to AOT compile Clojure from Java

Tags: clojure

Is it legitimate to compile Clojure from Java using `clojure.lang.Compiler.compile`?

Our Java application used to create instances of Clojure objects by using `clojure.lang.Compiler.load` on a .clj source which had a `proxy` macro.
Now we want to AOT compile these objects using `gen-class` rather than `proxy`. This is so the .class files can be moved around and we instantiate the objects later on.

The best I’ve managed so far is to convince `clojure.lang.Compiler.compile` to produce me the loader classfile (“my/domain/lib__init.class”). But I didn’t seem to get the accompanying .class files, one per function in the namespace (“my/domain/lib$fnname__1234.class”) and a stub class file for each `gen-class`. This is in a sandbox using the very simple first example at http://clojure.org/compilation. I thought I’d correctly set *compile-path*, and set it to something in the classpath, but maybe there’s still an issue there.

In any case, our actual application is RCP (Eclipse) based, which probably means they'll be more to figure out in terms of OSGI classloader classpath. In the meantime I’m just wondering if using `clojure.lang.Compiler.compile` directly is even a valid approach?

**Edit:** So I've now got it producing all the .class files, but it needed various bits of undocumented initializing which suggests to me that methods on `clojure.lang.Compiler` are meant to be internal. I had to set *compile-path* appropriately and *compile-files* to true, e.g.

```
RT.var("clojure.core", "*compile-files*").bindRoot(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use [`clojure.core/compile`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5537) function. Also you can check out how lein handles the `:aot` param to do [aot compilation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/compile.clj#L113).

Comment: I believe Ankur's suggestion is to call `clojure.core/compile` directly from Java: `RT.var("clojure.core", "compile").invoke(...)`. Grabbing vars and executing them from Java is far less error-prone and less confusing than trying to use the Java internals of clojure. If I recall correctly, this is how the Datomic Java API is implemented.

Comment: @DaveRay: Yup, thats what I meant by calling this from java

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of driving the Clojure compiler directly from Java.

```
        String clojureScript = "(ns user) (def hello (fn [] \"Hello world\"))";
        String notionalScriptFileName="hello.clj";
        String outputDirectory="/my/output/dir";

        Var compilePath = RT.var("clojure.core", "*compile-path*");            
        Var compileFiles = RT.var("clojure.core", "*compile-files*");

        Var.pushThreadBindings(RT.map(compilePath, outputDirectory, compileFiles, Boolean.TRUE));                        
        Compiler.compile(new StringReader(clojureScript), notionalScriptFileName, notionalScriptFileName);
        Var.popThreadBindings();
```

I've tested this with Clojure 1.4.0... your mileage may vary with other versions.

As the API stands you need to provide a "notional" file name. This only seems to be used to generate the .class file names. The class files it generates are written to the outputDirectory.